# Cálculos con duraciones de tiempo

Tags: excel, tabla-dinámica

Tengo una tabla con duraciones de tareas e formato [h]:mm:ss que luego en una tabla dinámica me suma perfectamente los valores

[image: tabla origen de datos]

[image: TD]

Pero en un campo calculado tengo que multiplicar la duración por el coste hporario de cada empleado y aqui ya me pierdo por que si multiplico la columna Duration * Tarifa lo que obtengo no se muy bien como lo cacula.

Por ejemplo si en el caso un empleado con tarifa de 46,27€ la hora se encuentra con una duration de 5:26:00 me calcula un total de 20,95€ que no es correcto obviamente.

Entiendo que tendré que separar las horas, minutos y segundos y ahcer el calculo por separado pero no se como obtener esas horas y minutos y segundos de la columna Duration por que las funcions HORA() MINUTO() no van con este formato de celda

En fin si a alguien se le ocurre algo lo agradeceria

Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Para que los calculos se realizan corretamente el campo calculado Coste debe ser

Coste=Duration x Tarifa x 24

Es decir, al multiplicar por 24 te lo calcula bien

Un saludo